# Is there a way to clear text and select box field inside html form via java script function?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to clear input text and select box field inside html form via java script function?

Comment: yes there is..! but first you could have shown your attempt..!

Comment: what did you try so for?

Comment: Use a reset button (no script required)? To reset a form using script call its reset method: `form.reset()` which will set all values to their defaults.

Comment: Inside HTML Form we have lot of text field as well as select box .So we need to write a generic java script function for clearing text fields as well as select fields by using HTML form name as input

Comment: form.reset() will set all values to their defaults.Is there a way to use clearing text and select box input field alone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my answer...

```
function clearFields(formName)
{
      var formElements = formName.elements;
      for(var i=0;i<formElements.length;i++)
      {
            var elementType = formElements[i].type;
            if('text' == elementType){
                  formElements[i].value="";
                                formElements[i].disabled = false;
            }
            else if('select-one' == elementType){
                  formElements[i].selectedIndex = 0;
                  formElements[i].disabled = false;
            }
            else if('select-multiple' == elementType)
            {
                  var multiOptions = formElements[i].options;
                  for(var j=0;j<multiOptions.length;j++)
                  {
                        multiOptions[j].selected = false;
                  }
            }
      }
}
```

Comment: Why are you changing the disabled property? Why not set the value of text inputs to their default value? For select elements, you should check the default selected attribute of the options rather than just setting the first one to selected (maybe there should be none selected?).

Comment: Logically speaking, while clearing the form, all the fields should be cleared and the first field is the default selected one. In case resetting to original value, the default value has to be stored somewhere and assign it to corresponding GUI elements while resetting.

Comment: —if no option is set as the default selected, there is no specification that requires a browser to set the first one as selected (and some don't) which is why one option should be set as the default selected option. What about a multiple select? The default value of various types of inputs and textarea elements is stored in their [*defaultValue*](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#dom-input-defaultvalue) property.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#textbox').val("");
    }
```

Comment: We are not using JQuery for doing this .How to achieve this without using JQuery ?

Comment: document.getElementById('textbox').value = "";

Comment: Are you want to do it on any button click event or page load?

Comment: we need to write a generic java script function for clearing text fields as well as select fields by using HTML form name as input .It will be difficult to pass all text field id for java script function

Answer (score 0):

You can use an HTML reset button (no script required):

```
<form>
  <!-- any number of form controls -->

  <input type="reset" value="Reset all controls to their default values">
</form>
```

Or if you really must use script, call the form's reset method:

```
// Assuming there's one form in the document
document.forms[0].reset();
```

If you want to reset particular controls of a form, and assuming that *form* is a reference to a form element, then:

```
var controls = form.elements;
for (var i=0, iLen=elements.length; i<iLen; i++) {
  if ( /* some test to filter controls */ ) {

    // set control to its default value
    resetControlValue(controls[i]);
  }
}
```

or similar. Though in the second case you need to also filter on the type of control to set the state of checkboxes and radio buttons, and for select elements set their selectedIndex to the index of the default selected option (if there is one) or to multiple default selected options.

A reset button is simpler. A function to reset form controls to their default value (or checked-ness or selected-ness) is a bit of work:

```
function resetControlValue(control) {
  var tagName = control.tagName.toLowerCase();

  // Do inputs and textareas
  if (tagName == 'input' || tagName == 'textarea') {

    // Set radios and checkboxes to their default checked state
    if (control.type == 'radio' || control.type == 'checkbox') {
      control.checked = control.defaultChecked;

    // Set text inputs and textareas to their default value
    // Include buttons
    } else if (control.type != 'button'  || tagName == 'textarea') {
      control.value = control.defaultValue;
    }

  // Set select elements to their default selected option
  } else if (tagName == 'select') {

    // Clear all selected inputs
    control.selectedIndex = -1;

    // Set default selected as selected
    for (var i=0, iLen=control.options.length; i<iLen; i++) {

      if (control.options[i].defaultSelected) {

        // If single select, leave after setting first
        if (control.type == 'select-one') {
          control.selectedIndex = i;
          return;
        }

        // If multipe, set all default selected
        control.options[i].selected = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Using javascript alone you can

```
document.getElementById('idoftextinput').value = "";
```

Be sure you have id attribute in your input and select elements